# Grouping subject data for within-subject analysis in SPSS

Tags: spss, repeated-measures

I have over 30 subjects who each did the same task about 50 times. Each of these data point can be in condition a1 or a2 of variable A or condition b1, b2, b3 or b4. So for each subject, I have datapoints for a1b1, a2b2, etc.

I have three dependent variables (v1, v2, v3) for each data point.

I understand that this is a within-subject analysis, done through a repeated measure test.

But the way I understand it, if I want to compare a1 to a2, I have to make a column for a1 with each subject's average for a1, the same for a2, and compare those two columns. And I have to do it for each dependent variable, and then again for b1-b4. And if I want to study the interaction, I have to do the same for a1b1, a2b1, a1b2, and so on, again for each dependent variable. This seems quite impractical.

As of now, my data is set with a column for subject's ID, a column for A condition, a column for B condition, a column for each dependent variable v1 v2 and v3, and a row for each data point.

Is there a way to do the repeated measure analysis as follows?

```
"(average of v1 when A=a1 for each subject) vs (average of v2 when A=a2 for each subjet)"
```

Comment: *(note: as my knowledge of statistics and SPSS is quite limited, I understand this question might be lacking and/or not clear. please don't hesitate to suggest edits)*

Comment: Would a 2-way repeated measures ANOVA for each DV work? https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/two-way-repeated-measures-anova-using-spss-statistics.php#procedure

Comment: @paul Well that's actually exactly what I am trying to do. The issue is that I need to define two new columns for a1 and a2, then four more for b1 and b2, and ***then*** 8 more for each interaction of A and B. For each DV, so that's 42 columns. I'm surprised there is not a way to group all data using another variable (for example, having a column 'subject' with each subject's ID and group all data with the same subject's ID)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. A 2-way ANOVA has 2 IVs (A & B). A is binary, one column, vals are 0 and 1 with labels a1 and a2. I don't see why you need two new columns for a1 and a2 If that's the case then there's a problem with your question, because a column should be one variable (A). You don't use a column per condition. B col has 4 values (again one col, nominal var, if ranked then ordinal var). You don't code the interaction as a column, it's calculated in the ANOVA (A*B). You may want to stick to 2 univariate ANOVAs. MANOVAs are harder to interpret, but you can try for v1 vs v2,

Comment: @paul Well, I might be mistaken, but in the link above the example has 2 IVs and ends up having 6 columns to represent all interactions. Or is there something I'm missing? (thanks for the help by the way :))

Comment: Ah, sorry, got it I was thinking of the between-subjects, which looks like this: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/two-way-anova-using-spss-statistics.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to *restructure* the data, transforming it from the long to wide format. Here's some links to tutorials (googled):

- [Tutorial from Indiana University IT services](http://kb.iu.edu/data/bbqj.html)
- [tutorial video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GNRFeHAVy0)
- [SPSS/IBM reference manual section](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/rd_overview.htm)

Quoted from http://kb.iu.edu/data/bbqj.html:

> "The long format uses multiple rows for each observation or
>   participant:

```
ID  WEIGHT  CALORIES  TIME
1   200    3500        1
1   190    3300        2
1   180    3100        3
2   160    3000        1
2   150    2900        2
2   140    2800        3
```

> The wide format uses one row for each observation or participant:

```
ID  weight1 weight2 weight3 calories1 calories2 calories3
1   200      190    180       3500     3300     3100
2   160      150    140       3000     2900     2800         "
```

The wizard is in *Data* > *Restructure* > *Restructure selected cases into variables* (second option).

Once the data is in this format you can run the [two-way ANOVA for repeated measures](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/two-way-repeated-measures-anova-using-spss-statistics.php#procedure) (Analyze > General Linear Model > Repeated Measures...).